# How to create a unique room ID for users to join in Firebase (iOS Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want users to be able to search for a unique room ID to join the room. Much like Clash Royale's tournament room ID or Clash of Clan's clan ID (ex. #JY9QGQ).

Comment: please have a look at the [guide: "how do i ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask").

Comment: Consider using `childByAutoId()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#append_to_a_list_of_data

Comment: `childByAutoId()` is very long and ugly. I am looking for a 7 chars combination that user can take advantage of.